# How to implement a combination of behaviours for my objects

Tags: c#, object-oriented, abstraction

I need to create a program to manage an association.

Members of this association have different roles and each role has specific characteristics.
My problem is that I'm not able to abstract this concept in my program.
This is what I thought so far.

Create a class `Person` that has generic attributes for members and not members such as `Name`, `Surname`, `Birthdate`, etc. Then create a class `Member` that inherits from `Person` adding some attributes for the members such as `Id`, `EnrollmentDate`, etc.

As regards the role, I thought to use interfaces. For example, if a member is an instructor, `IInstructor`, if he/she is a vehicles manager, `IVehiclesManager`, etc. and each one has a different behaviour.

My problem is that a member for example can be both an instructor and a vehicles manager and I don't know how to implement this.
Do I have to create three different classes, one that implements `IInstructor`, one `IVehiclesManager` and one that implements both or is there another way to do this?

The problem is that there are various roles and each member can have any combination of these.

It's the first time I use interfaces and maybe I'm missing something.
Am I on the right way or should I use a totally different approach?

Comment: Congratulations, you've unlocked "Wizards and Warriors"!  https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Comment: @bitsoflogic: Nice. :-)

Comment: Advice, drop the `I` in your `IInterfaces`. As far as your domain logic should be concerned it is dealing with an `Instructor` not an `IInstructor` unless its your domain is concerned specifically with Apple Instructors. Anything interacting with your domain logic will probably pass in `SQLInstructor`, `data.Instructor`, or `who cares how it was defined and named type` which are instances of `domain.Instructor`.

Comment: @Kain0_0 Using an uppercase I in front of the name of every interface is the standard for C# though. Being the bad version of Hungarian notation, it's not the best option _technically_, but if you don't do this, your code will confuse pretty much every C# programmer.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: It's not Hungarian notation, or even the moral equivalent of it.  Java does the same thing with `Interface` and `InterfaceImpl`, just more poorly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Then I stand corrected. However, I'm a bit surprised by the comment about Java. I've only ever seen it like in Android, e.g. an interface called `Adapter` and an implementation called `ArrayAdapter`, which is a convention I see no issue with.

Comment: @R.Schmitz: Yep, that is a fine convention.  Hard to tell if Adapter is an interface, an abstract class or a concrete class just by looking at it, but that's what they also said about Hungarian.  Prefixes and suffixes are like salt and pepper; a little goes a long way, but too much just ruins your food.

Comment: @R.Schmitz It may be the convention, but it is a bad convention. Imagine calling your friend 'Human Bob'. Good tools will provide you with exactly the same information, and inform you of simple mistakes. There are certainly times when it pays to add some prefix or suffix to differentiate something, I suggested one earlier `SQLInstructor` at least here it is informing me that this is a very SQLish `Instructor`. I do not see any reason to tolerate laziness in word choice, an `InstructorAdaptor` is hardly informative, `NovosoftInstructor` is far more informative and can still be an 'adaptor'.

Comment: @Kain0_0 I already said that it's not the ideal way to do it, so I don't get what your idea is here - write code that will confuse almost anybody else, for the sake of saving one letter? Rewrite all existing C# code?

Comment: @R.Schmitz Fair enough, I came across pretty harshly before. Onto your question: I don't see how a developer worth their salt would be confused by dropping the spurious `I` from the name of interface. It certainly isn't about saving a letter. If that was the case call it `Instrctr` it saves a few more letters. Nor am I in favour of a whole rewrite just because someone picked a bad name. My point was to learn from previous mistakes, poor naming, and improve on it. Don't just add a prefix or a suffix because of convention, pick the name meaningfully, and enrich it beyond the syntax.

Comment: @Kain0_0 No, it didn't come across as harsh, no problem. I'm not talking about "confused" as in you don't know left from right anymore, I'm talking about reading the source and assuming that that thing without an `I` is not an interface. It's actually _necessary_ to _be worth your salt_ (to have enough experience in C#) to fall into that trap - whereas the absolute beginners are the ones who would have less issues with leaving out the `I`, because they are not used to the language's standard yet.

Comment: @R.Schmitz  I can certainly agree that convention can make programming much less stressful when everyone plays by the same rules, and there are cases, such as with data structure and pointers, where convention is the only and very much necessary guard rail. This isn't the case for C# interfaces though, the compiler is well aware and will inform you clearly about any mistake you might make. Prepending an `I` to each interface name is simply a convention waiting to cause confusion instead of guard against it for exactly that reason. `class ISee` was that intended to be an interface?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to approach it from different angle.

Don't start with classes, start with behaviour your application should have.

In question you mentioned only static structure of the data you expecting to have in your application. So I assume that first behaviors you need to implement would be:

- Create a member
- Add a role to the member
- Display member information
- Member can execute actions provided by roles member has (press a button in UI for example)

Then working approach would look like below

#### Create a member

- Create a class `Member` containing properties required for member creation
- Create a view for `Member` class
- Create a class which will receive member data and save it to the persistence layer of your choice(file system, database etc).

```
public class Member
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

#### Add role to the member

- Because different roles will have different behaviours, but from the member point of view should be treated in a same way - we will introduce roles as an abstraction `IRole`.
- Create concrete Roles by implementing `IRole`
- Add collection of roles to the member by adding `Roles` collection to the `Member` class
- Create view where roles can be added to the member
- Create class which will link members with their roles and saves this link to the persistence layer of your choice.

```
public interface IRole
{
    void ExecuteAction();
}

public class Instructor : IRole
{
    public void ExecuteAction() => { } // write instructions
}

public class IVehiclesManager : IRole
{
    public void ExecuteAction() => { } // allow to use vehicles by members
}

// Member class will change 

public class Member
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, IRole> Actions { get: set; }

    public void Execute(int roleId) => Actions[roleId].ExecuteAction();
}
```

#### Display member information

- Create a view(if not created already in previous steps) which will display member's information
- Add a view with the button to execute action of member's roles

Answer (score 1):

### The Spec

I'd advise you to take another look at the functional specification and identify nouns, because a lot of those will become class names in your program.

If there is no functional specification, create one. I don't like writing documentation either, but trust me, it will prevent so many headaches. If that seems a bit overwhelming right now, just have a relaxed read of [this series of articles](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/10/02/painless-functional-specifications-part-1-why-bother/), it will explain why and how and has a template to get started. Ultimately it's just explaining to other people what the app does, so not that much different from what you did when you wrote this question.

### Nouns

One of the sentences in this question will probably end up in that specification as it is:

> Members of this association have different roles and each role has specific characteristics.

The nouns here are "Members", "association", "roles" and "characteristics". Your specific issue concerned the combination of members and roles. What's important to note here is that "role" is a noun. Long story short, a `Role` would make a good class. Even if a `Role` ends up containing nothing more than that name-string, it still makes sense because it allows you to *say in code* "There is a `Role` and I give it the name "Instructor". There is another `Role` and I give it the name "Vehicle Manager".

You can then connect these roles to members in different ways, the simplest among them being a `Role` just having a list of `Member`s. If a `Member` wants to manage vehicles, you check if they have an entry in the vehicle manager `Role`. How exactly you solve that will depend heavily on the rest of your app though.

### Some more advice

I'd advise you to avoid inheritance. It's overhyped by universities and tutorials. Every time you are tempted to use inheritance, think if you can't use composition instead. This wasn't *really* the issue in this case, but you *will* ultimately run into the problems described in [the link user bitsoflogic commented under your question](https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/).

As an example, I'd like to cite your given structure, `Person` and `Member`. Does a non-member person even make sense in your application? If a person is a user who has not logged in yet, then you have no idea what their name, surname, and date of birth are.

Now, it's understandable if you want the personal information name, surname, and date of birth separate from other more business-oriented data. You will just run into  less problems if you use composition instead: Just make every `Member` have an instance of a new class `PersonalInformation` which contains name, surname, and date of birth.